# Logical Error in binding Dataset in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dataset

I have tried attribute DataSource, DataSourceID of Grid view element. 
The .aspx.cs code is

```
        DataSet ds = instance_face.get_task(emp);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Dataset is returned by the function call

```
    instance_face.get_task(emp);
```

But it's not working, there is no syntax error in the code. The command successfully executed but does not display in the GUI.

Comment: check ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count is grater than zero.

Comment: if you can copy ur UI code here, it would be useful

Comment: UI code can not be copied , The site don't allow UI code

Comment: Really, that doesn't sound even remotely true.

Comment: Thanks @SainPradeep , The query was returning no row in  a dataset.